# stating implements Iterable<T> is redundant

Tags: javascript, typescript, iterator, iterable

My class wraps an iterable object and implements iteration as:

```
[Symbol.iterator]() { return this.range[Symbol.iterator](); }
```

The compiler *does not enforce* the `implements Iterable<T>` info - why is that?

```js
class SomeWrapper /* implements Iterable<number> */ {
  constructor(public readonly range: MyRange) {}
  [Symbol.iterator]() { return this.range[Symbol.iterator](); }
}

class MyRange {
  constructor(
    public readonly begin: number,
    public readonly end: number
  ) {}

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return new MyRangeIterator(this);
  }
}

class MyRangeIterator implements Iterator<number>
{
  public index: number
  public end: number

  constructor(range: MyRange)
  {
    this.index = range.begin;
    this.end = range.end 
  }

  public next(): IteratorResult<number, "no_more_values">
  {
    if (this.index < this.end) {
      return { done: false, value: this.index++ }
    }
    return { done: true, value: "no_more_values" }
  }
}
```

usage:

```
const range = new MyRange(5, 14);
const wrapper = new SomeWrapper(range)
for (const x of wrapper) { // I expected an error here: SomeWrapper - Not Iterable
  console.log(x)
}
```

Comment: The point of `implements` is to enforce that the class adheres to the interface. If it does not, it's a compilation error. If you remove that, then it's not a compilation error for the class to be incompatible with `Iterable<T>`, but you'll end up with errors wherever you try to use an instance of the class as `Iterable<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't check if your class `implements` `Iterable` but checks if your class has `Symbol.iterator` property.

It will no longer typecheck when you remove this property or make this property not to return an iterator.

[Iterators and Generators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html) explains it.

> An object is deemed iterable if it has an implementation for the Symbol.iterator property.

TypeScript typechecks in this way in general as it's based on [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

For example, this typechecks even though `Y` doesn't `implements` `X`.

```
interface X {
    readonly x: string;
}

class Y {
    readonly x: string = 'y';
}

function f(x: X): void {}

f(new Y());
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. Is it considered good documentation in such cases? or not even that?

Comment: It works as a good documentation for users of the class. Also, the type checker will let you know when you forgot to implement such properties or implemented them with wrong types.